# Quarkus logging level INFO covers JAVA_OPTS logging.level DEBUG

Tags: java, kubernetes, logging, slf4j, quarkus

In my project since we moved to new keycloak version we started using quarkus as a logging system. When I setup quarkus.logging.level = DEBUG on my kubernetes cluster it's too verbose. What I want to achieve is that my quarkus logging level = INFO but in same time (just for testing some scenarios) I would like to provide to the console logging from my java code. slf4j is what I use in my application to log some info during the flow.

```
log.debug("Some debug logging information");
```

I was reading about quarkus categories but non of them fits to slf4j directly.
If I set quarkus lvl = INFO and in same time
JAVA_OPTS - Dlogging.level ..... =DEBUG
it won't work. quarkus covers old kind of properties we were using in past.

Any tip how can I manage that kind scenario?

Comment: Are you talking about [keycloakX](https://www.keycloak.org/2020/12/first-keycloak-x-release.adoc)? If so, this might be a question better asked on the [keycloak mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/keycloak-user).

Comment: yes, I'm talkin about that